# XML integer format in odoo form view

Tags: xml, format, integer, odoo-12

I want the user to enter only an integer as a reference, so I created an integer field.

The problem is the number prints with thousands separator. I still want to keep the thousand separator for other integer fields.

How can I format this field using XML?

I am new to odoo and using Saas along with studio.

I have only found solutions for QWeb reports:

```
 <xpath expr="/t[1]/t[1]/div[1]/div[26]/div[1]/span[3]" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="t-options-widget">"text"</attribute>
 </xpath>
```

I did not find a way with:

```
decoration-{$name}
```

I have also tried XML widget but its not working with "text":

```
<field name="x_studio_int_field" string="My Integer Field" widget="text"/>
```

It allows the user to input text, then a server error pops up if text is inputed (instead of odoo error).

Thanks for your help

Maxime

Comment: So, you want to format an integer field displayed on a form view, right?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I want!

Comment: I have tried other things but not really working (I have edited my question with what I tried).